# Get background color of GtkEntry

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Getting colors of regular widgets (GtkWidget) is pretty easy.

I am just getting `GtkStyleContext` and calling `get_background_color` function. But I can't get background colors of widgets like `GtkTreeView` or `GtkEntry`.

So the question is how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution:   gtk_style_context_get_style_property(in context,in prop_str, out value). prop_str is style property name (section  "Style Properties" in widgets documentation, different widgets have different ones).

Comment: `out_value` has the type `(GValue *)`, how do you cast it to `(GdkRGBA *)` then ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.... 
You should supply "background-color" as prop_str in gtk_style_context_get_style_property function which will return background color.